# Interpretation of java error on mac terminal

Tags: java, macos, exception, terminal, runtime-error

I have compiled and run a java code on the mac terminal, and I am trying to debug it. But I am not able to pin point the location of the error from the error message

The error is

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
 at com.chimpler.example.fpm.ResultReader.readMapping(ResultReader.java:44)
 at com.chimpler.example.fpm.ResultReader.main(ResultReader.java:136)
```

What do the numbers 44 and 136 mean?

The ResultReader.java file has only 124 lines

Comment: Those are line numbers in the source file.

Comment: That is the funny part, the source code has only 124 lines

Comment: Then either you or the compiler is wrong.

Comment: If your source file currently have 124 lines, and the code fails on line 136, then you forgot to recompile the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are references to the lines 44 and 136 in the source file for `ResultReader` which you can see [here](https://github.com/fredang/mahout-frequent-pattern-mining-example/blob/master/src/main/java/com/chimpler/example/fpm/ResultReader.java).

Comment: Got it thanks. I forgot that the import lines were added on top of the actual code. Thanks a lot for your help.